# Selecting class element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some elements on my page. These are some of them:

```
<div class="tile 11"></div>
<div class="tile 35"></div>
<div class="tile 89"></div>
```

And I want a CLASS of element go into the variable any time I hover it.

I tried

```
$(".tile").mouseenter(function(){            //on mouse over
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");    //check if selected
  myVariable = $(this).css;                  //then place css into variable
    }).mouseleave(function() {               //..and when I leave it
      $( this ).removeAttr( "style" );       //remove color
});
```

But it didnt work.

For example, when I hover the first tile, the "myVariable" should be "tile 11" but it isn't. Why?

Comment: Try `$(this).attr("class")` instead of `$(this).css`

Comment: @SandeepNayak that really worked. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy. You need to use `$(this).attr("class")` like shown below.

```js
$(".tile").mouseenter(function(){            //on mouse over
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");    //check if selected
  var myVariable = $(this).attr("class");                  //then place css into variable
  alert(myVariable);  
}).mouseleave(function() {               //..and when I leave it
      $( this ).removeAttr( "style" );       //remove color
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile 11">div 1</div>
<div class="tile 35">div 2</div>
<div class="tile 89">div 3</div>
```

Comment: This works, thanks so much guys! ;) Ill accept your answer in 9 minutes